# Alfresco webscript dynamic URLs

Tags: url, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I am exploring the use of dynamic URLS within an Alfresco webscript that will allow users to bookmark pages.

Based on initial research, it doesn't seem like it is possible due to the structure of webscripts and registering urls. Check out [this link](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/178779-dynamic-webscript-url-path) for an answer to what I assume is the same question as I am posting.

If anyone has any experience creating dynamic URLs within an Alfresco webscript, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you need to be dynamic in your URL? WebScripts allow you to pass arguments in either the path or the query string. Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: Hi [Jeff Potts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736391/jeff-potts), thanks for the reply and help. I ended up passing parameters to the end of the URL, which meets my requirements perfectly. It worked out great and users can now bookmark pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass dynamic parameters to the url like this

```
<url>/api/workflow-instances/{workflow_instance_id}/task-instances?authority={authority?}</url>
```

But you can't create dynamic URLs of webscript,
Or you have to create Webscript files in **Data Dictionary / Webscripts** folder for dynamic approach.

Comment: Thanks [vikash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7069316/vikash), this worked out great as I commented above to [Jeff Potts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736391/jeff-potts). Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked from alfresco community is definitely something different than what you explained. If you want to bookmark the search results page or folder listing or even a document details page in share, that is definitely possible out of the box and AFAIK you do not even need customization s for it.